# How to write a typescript definition file for a node module that exports a function?

Tags: typescript, commonjs

Consider, for the toml node module I can simply use:

```
// toml.d.ts
declare module TOML {
    export function parse(value:string):any;
}

declare module "toml" {
    export = TOML;
}
```

Then:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../defs/toml/toml.d.ts"/>
import toml = require('toml');
toml.parse(...);
```

However, what about node module that export only a single function, such as 'glob' (https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob).

The node usage of this module would be:

```
var glob = require("glob")
glob("*.js", {}, callback(err, files) { ... });
```

You'd naively expect you could do this:

```
// glob.d.ts
declare function globs(paths:string, options:any, callback:{(err:any, files:string[]):void;
```

...but because typescripts 'import' semantics are a bit strange, it seems you can only use the 'import .. = require()' statement to alias *modules*. Trying to call:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../defs/glob/glob.d.ts"/>
import blog = require('glob');
```

Results in:

```
error TS2072: Module cannot be aliased to a non-module type.
```

#### So, how would you write a definition file for this?

NB. Notice that this is for a *commonjs* module using node, *not* an AMD module.

...also yes, I know you can do this by breaking the type system using declare, but I'm trying to avoid that:

```
declare var require;
var glob = require('glob');
glob(...);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `export =`.

Definition:

```
declare module 'glob' {
  function globs(paths: string, options: any, callback: (err: any, files: string[]) => void): any;
  export = globs;
}
```

Usage (with [esModuleInterop enabled](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bx4AjADk6eQ)):

```
import glob from 'glob';
glob("*.js", {}, (err, files) => { });
```

Comment: In TypeScript 2 this gives me the following error: `error TS2306: File 'glob.d.ts' is not a module.` :(

Comment: I'm using TS version 2.6.2 and it works for me. Thank you!

Comment: How do you specify an exported function that with properties. For example: https://github.com/Schoonology/weighted/blob/master/lib/weighted.js#L97-L98?

Answer (score 2):

Basarat's answer doesn't work with typescript 2.1.5. You need to declare function and export with `export =`:

```
export = MyFunction;
declare function MyFunction(): string;
```

[How to write a definition file for commonjs module that exports function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891795/how-to-write-a-definition-file-for-commonjs-module-that-exports-function?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Basarat's answer works for me and I'm on version 2.6.2