# How to write a definition file for commonjs module that exports function

Tags: typescript, commonjs, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I want to use simple commonjs module in typescript, and here are 3 files

original lib:

```
//commonjs-export-function.js
module.exports = function() {
    return 'func';
};
```

definition file:

```
//commonjs-export-function.d.ts
declare function func(): string;
export = func;
```

typescript program which use it:

```
//main.ts
import { func } from './commonjs-function';

console.log(func());
```

When I run tsc I get this error:

```
tsc main.ts && node main.js
main.ts(1,22): error TS2497: Module '"/Users/aleksandar/projects/typescript-playground/commonjs-function"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.
```

here is also already answered question but it doesn't work with typescript 2.0

[How to write a typescript definition file for a node module that exports a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029462/how-to-write-a-typescript-definition-file-for-a-node-module-that-exports-a-funct)

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution in typescript docs here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-function-d-ts.html

```
*~ Note that ES6 modules cannot directly export callable functions.
*~ This file should be imported using the CommonJS-style:
*~   import x = require('someLibrary');
...
export = MyFunction;
declare function MyFunction(): string;
```

so mu definition file should be:

```
//commonjs-export-function.d.ts
declare function func(): string;
export = func;
```

and import with require:

```
//main.ts
import func = require('./commonjs-export-function');
```

Comment: Wow, finally find the solution, that saves my day, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've recently had trouble finding examples of CommonJS module definitions compatible with TypeScript 2.8.x. Here's an attempt to demonstrate the approach using [map-promise-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-map-limit), a package with [a single CommonJS export](https://github.com/dbrockman/promise-map-limit/blob/master/index.js#L3):

```
declare module 'promise-map-limit' {

  type IIteratee<T, R> = (value: T) => Promise<R> | R;

  function mapLimit<T, R>(
    iterable: Iterable<T>,
    concurrency: number,
    iteratee: IIteratee<T, R>
  ): Promise<R[]>;

  export = mapLimit;

}
```

In summary, to create a type definition for a CommonJS module with a single function-type export:

- Use the same `declare module` syntax as you'd use for any other [ambient module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules)
- Declare a named function (without using the `declare` keyword) within the module body
- Export the function with `export =` instead of `export default`

[Edit] Realized this is similar to [basarat's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24030295/1991086). Good deal!

Answer (score 0):

for CommonJS use
module.exorts = variable_name

for es2015 use
export default const/let variable_name
OR
variable defination

export default variable_name